# How to change php array keys

Tags: php, arrays

This is my php array:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 [21] => 0 [22] => 0 [23] => 0 [24] => 0 [25] => 0 [26] => 0 [27] => 0 [28] => 0 [29] => 0 [30] => 0 [31] => 0 [32] => 0 [33] => 0 [34] => 0 [35] => 0 [36] => 0 [37] => 0 [38] => 0 [39] => 0 [40] => 0 [41] => 0 [42] => 0 [43] => 0 [44] => 0 [45] => 0 [46] => 0 [47] => 0 [48] => 0 [49] => 0 [50] => 0 [51] => 0 [52] => 0 [53] => 0 [54] => 0 [55] => 0 [56] => 0 [57] => 0 [58] => 0)
```

i want to change it as following:

```
Array (  [59] => 0 [60] => 0 [61] => 0 [62] => 0 [63] => 0 [64] => 0 [65] => 0 [66] => 0 [67] => 0 [68] => 0 [69] => 0 [70] => 0 [71] => 0 [72] => 0 [73] => 0 [74] => 0 [75] => 0 [76] => 0 [77] => 0 [78] => 0 [79] => 0 [80] => 0 [81] => 0 [82] => 0 [83] => 0 [84] => 0 [85] => 0 [86] => 0 [87] => 0 [88] => 0 [89] => 0 [90] => 0 [91] => 0 [92] => 0 [93] => 0 [94] => 0 [95] => 0 [96] => 0 [97] => 0 [98] => 0 [99] => 0 [100] => 0 [101] => 0 [102] => 0 [103] => 0 [104] => 0 [105] => 0 [106] => 0 [107] => 0 [108] => 0 [109] => 0 [110] => 0 [111] => 0 [112] => 0 [113] => 0 [114] => 0 [115] => 0 [116] => 0)
```

need it as a new array begin with `59`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You would have to build new array with desired keys inserting old values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
  $newArray[$key+59]=$value;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: It looks incomplete without array initialization. :^ )

Comment: Although that wasn't required but i just added it for your nicely worded comment :)

Answer (score 1):

it should be dynamic, I will not use "+59" as it will act as static.
Try this:

```
$oldArray = Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 .... [57] => 0 [58] => 0)
```

Now will find the last key of array.you can do this by many ways eg:

```
function lastKey($anyArray){
   end($anyArray);
   return key($anyArray);
}

$lastKey = lastkey($oldArray); //Last key of the old array i.e. in your case 58.

$newArray=array();
$newKeyOffset = $lastKey+1;
foreach($oldArray as $key=>$value)
{
   $newArray[$key+$newkeyoffset]=$value;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_combine` with a new set of keys and the original values:

`$new_array = array_combine(range(59, 59+count($array)-1), array_values($array));`

Answer (score 0):

If result array keys does not intersect with original array keys you could save the memory by using the same array.

```
$array = array_fill_keys(range(0, 58), 0); // creation of test array
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
    unset($array[$key]);
    $array[$key + 59] = $value;
    }

echo json_encode($array); 
// {"59":0,"60":0,"61":0,"62":0,"63":0,"64":0,"65":0,"66":0,"67":0,"68":0,"69":0,"70":0,"71":0,"72":0,"73":0,"74":0,"75":0,"76":0,"77":0,"78":0,"79":0,"80":0,"81":0,"82":0,"83":0,"84":0,"85":0,"86":0,"87":0,"88":0,"89":0,"90":0,"91":0,"92":0,"93":0,"94":0,"95":0,"96":0,"97":0,"98":0,"99":0,"100":0,"101":0,"102":0,"103":0,"104":0,"105":0,"106":0,"107":0,"108":0,"109":0,"110":0,"111":0,"112":0,"113":0,"114":0,"115":0,"116":0,"117":0}
```